# Analysis of Weighted Quick Union with Path Compression

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, amortized-analysis

I have searched the internet for an analysis of why WQUPC is amortized $O( m \alpha (n) ) $ for m operations on n nodes ( $\alpha ( n) $ is the inverse Ackerman function).

I understand why it is $O ( m \log^{\ast} ( n ) ) $ as it is proven [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_O%28log*n%29_time_complexity_of_union%E2%80%93find?wprov=sfla1).

So the question is, why is WQUPC $O( m \alpha (n) ) $? I would prefer a rigorous analysis, but an intuitive explanation would also be useful.

Comment: Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al. has an explanation for WQUPC O(mα(n)). You can get the pdf at https://web.njit.edu/~wl256/download/cs610/Introduction-to-algorithm-3rdEdition.pdf .(p 573)